# How to shift signal by fractional step in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, shift

I have two signals from an oscilloscope. Each of them has 1000 points with a 1ns step. I need to see the difference between signals. But the signals are shifted by 0.31ns. I can create two plots with aligned signals with the command

```
plot(time, signal1, time+0.31, signal2);
```

But how can I plot the difference of de-shifted (aligned) signals?

Comment: The `+0.31` is just a visual trick, it doesn't change the data in any way. You'll need to interpolate both data sets to a common reference frame, e.g. interpolate `singal2` to the time stamps of `signal1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function:

```
vq = interp1(x,v,xq)
vq = interp1(x,v,xq,method)
vq = interp1(x,v,xq,method,extrapolation)
```

> `vq = interp1(x,v,xq)` returns interpolated values of a 1-D function
> at specific query points using linear interpolation. Vector x contains
> the sample points, and v contains the corresponding values, v(x).
> Vector xq contains the coordinates of the query points.

For your example try something like:

```
signal2_prime = interp1(time+0.31, signal2, time);
plot(time, signal1, time, signal2_prime)
```